# How to use auth middleware in own package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have controller in my package where i trying add auth middleware.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

So then I get error:

```
Class Auth\LoginController does not exist
```

What do I need to do to use auth middleware?

UPD

I read my question and realized that it is not quite accurate. I want in my package to have access to the views of the auth middleware, is there such an option?

Comment: You need to __require__ `illuminate/auth` package in your `composer.json`.

Comment: What is the controller class signature?

Comment: It seems that your application does not have Auth controller folder that shift with Laravel Default Auth. If you does not have yet then run php artisan make:auth. That will solve your problem.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I already tried to request `illuminate/auth`. It didn't help me, controllers and views didn't appear.

Comment: What do you mean "the views of the auth middleware"? Middleware and `illuminate/auth` don't have views. You just need to copy the auth views from laravel to your package, that's it.

Comment: @nmfzone As I understand it, the controller looks for views in the resources folder of the main project. So, I should copy all the controllers and override the routes in addition to the views?

Comment: What do you think if your consumer not using Laravel? I don't know what your goal is, but the reasonable use-case if someone needs to use auth, then they should extend from your package, not using `make:auth` anymore.

Comment: @nmfzone The package is created specifically for use in laravel. I need to make some routes secure, so I'm using auth middleware, I also want to use my own views for authorization in the package. the problem is that I do not quite understand how to do it.

Comment: Please take a look how "laravel package" works. For example from here https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/blob/master/src/ServiceProvider.php#L52

Comment: You must know, package don't know your consumer has "auth" resource views or not. So, instead of looking in the main project, you need to have the views in your package. Then you just tell the laravel to load views from your packages resource views.

Comment: @nmfzone I understand how to upload views to the service provider of the package, I have no understanding what to do next.
1) I created authorization views and registered them in the service provider of the package
2) I added the authorization controllers to my package

After that I received the error `Class Auth \ LoginController does not exist`. Whether correctly I understand that I need to register routes and not to use Auth :: routes ();

Comment: What? See your question. You say "I want in my package to have access to the views". So, what you want then? About your another question, do you have "LoginController" in your package? Please forget about main project. It's package, and you don't have access to the main project (thinking your package standalone).

Comment: Then, what do you mean `Auth::routes()` ? You don't say anything about it. Please see your question!

Comment: @nmfzone Yes, I solved the problem with the views and now I'm trying to register the routes for authorization

Comment: Hmmm. You can have something like this in your service provider https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/4.0/src/Passport.php#L110-L119

Comment: @nmfzone Thanks for the help, I already tried to use this construct and got the error `View [auth.login] not found.`

Comment: Of course, you don't have that view. You should extends the showLoginForm with `public function showLoginForm() { return view('your_package::auth.login'); }`. You should register the view like I said above, then copy the views in your package `resources/auth` folder.

Comment: I'm not sure if I answering your question. But glad if it helps!